# Android resize the Google map by cutting the part of top and bottom for centering the map

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I wonder how to resize the google map by cutting the top and bottom for customize the size in the app.

Since the google map will hide the viewstub (Which contains the tabLayout, fragment page and button), if I using animateCamera() or moveCamera() method to centering the map based on the markers. How can I implement the part for customize the google map's size?

Thanks.

[image: Cut the top and bottom of google map and reload it]

Comment: you can create new layout to display full map with cutting top-bottom view after click on above google map

Comment: I afraid that the layout will overdraw a lot......

Comment: use parallex effect in your code.so you don't write same code for other layout.it will just put animation.